# IndexError: string index out of range (Airflow & Python)

Tags: python, airflow

I am creating a process of transferring information from BigQuery to Cloud Storage via Airflow. I´m using a looping function that creates various tasks and the idea is to transfer information from all the tables we have that will come up automatically. But unfortunately I came across one more coding error in Python.

I looked at some similar questions but honestly couldn't associate it with my code and make it work properly. I know there is data in the "lista_tabelas" and "qtd_tabelas" variables. What can be tweaked in the code to make the process work as it should.

```
def get_data_from_bigquery():
    bq = bigquery.Client()
    query = """ SELECT dataset_id, table_id, CONCAT(dataset_id,'.',table_id) as dataset_table FROM dataset.__TABLES__  """
    query_job = bq.query(query)
    data = query_job.result()
    rows = list(data)
    qtd_tabelas = len(rows)
    Variable.set("lista_tabelas", rows)
    Variable.set("qtd_tabelas", int(qtd_tabelas))

def prepare_backup():
    a = Variable.get("lista_tabelas")
    a_len = Variable.get("qtd_tabelas")
    for i in range(int(a_len)):
        #print("Start - Dataset: %s, Table: %s, DataSet.Table: %s" %(a[i][0],a[i][1],a[i][2]))
        bq_to_gcp_json = BigQueryToCloudStorageOperator(
            task_id='bq_to_gcs_json',
            dag=dag,
            source_project_dataset_table='dataset_test:'+a[i][2],
            destination_cloud_storage_uris=['gs://'+nm_bucket+'/backup/'+a[i][0]+'/'+{{ ts_nodash }}+'/'+a[i][1]+'_*.json'],
            export_format='NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON',
            bigquery_conn_id='gcp')
        bq_to_gcp_json.set_upstream(Python_2)

Python_1 = PythonOperator(task_id='bq_list_tables',
    python_callable=get_data_from_bigquery,
    dag=dag)

Python_2 = PythonOperator(task_id='backup_all_tables',
    python_callable=prepare_backup,
    dag=dag)

Python_2.set_upstream(Python_1)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 926, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 113, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python_operator.py", line 118, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/airflow/dags/git/backup_bq_to_gcs.py", line 133, in prepare_backup
    source_project_dataset_table='dataset_test:'+a[i][2],
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: If `a` is a string, you shouldn't pass two indexes ot it.

Comment: It should be a list but I'll check how it is.

Comment: A list of values that contain strings. Then you should check that passing a constant value to it, works fine, maybe an item in the list doesn't reach a length of 3. and that's why the error. Clearly you are trying to call something somewhere it doesn't exist.